# Can the hamming distance be used with non-binary strcuture

Tags: algorithm, hamming-distance

It is known that the hamming distance is applied to calculate the difference between two binary strings. Is it possible to apply it to calculate the difference between non-binary structures?

Comment: You can always cast non-binary into binary

Comment: Also [this is hamming generalisation algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) called Levenshtein

Comment: It depends on a *particular* problem. If you can determine and specify how to calculate the difference between two objects then you obviously can compute a Hamming distance between them.

Answer (score 0):

The Hamming distance of two strings of the same length is the sum of the distance between each pair of corresponding bits (i.e., [L1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry)), where the latter distance is 0 for identical bits and 1 for nonidentical bits, (i.e., the [discrete metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_space)). If you want to apply Hamming distance to alphabets that are not binary, you can replace the discrete metric with another metric of your choice, e.g., [Lee distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lee_distance) is the distance between two numbers on a circle. If the strings have different lengths, then you have to change to something like Levenshtein distance, but even there, you can choose whatever deletion/insertion/substitution costs you want.